# Case when in Select, Left Join and Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

how can i archive the following?

If @chk = 0 then include 4th Column in result else keep only 3 Columns,
and if 4th Column is selected then Left join is needed for that 4th column, 
and include that 4th column in group by

```
DECLARE @chk AS INT= 0;
SELECT a.Ledgerid, 
       b.LedgerCity,
       CASE WHEN @chk = 0 THEN SUM(a.TotalAmount) ELSE SUM(a.NetAmount) END,
       CASE WHEN @chk = 0 THEN c.ledgername END  (is it possilbe to completly do not have this column if @chk <> 0)
FROM ExpenseMaster A
     LEFT JOIN LedgerAddress AS B ON A.LedgerID = B.LedgerID
     LEFT JOIN LedgerMaster AS C ON A.LedgerID = C.LedgerID  --This left join is required only if @chk=0, same logic is there in above select statement
GROUP BY A.LedgerID, 
         B.LedgerCity;
         C.LedgerName; -- this 3rd group required only if @chk=0
```

some posts suggested how to use case when in Group by. I tried "group by case when @chk=0 then a.Ledgerid,b.Ledgercity,c.LedgerName else a.Ledgerid,b.Ledgercity END; but this did not work

Comment: Add `AND @Chk = 0` to the `ON` clause?

Comment: leaving out a column from your resultset can only be achieved by using 2 seperate queries, and an `if ... else` on your `@chk` variable to determine which query to use. All other questions are perfect possible, see the comment of Larnu above

Comment: This query presumably isn't running in isolation.

What's wrong with leaving it blank and  allowing the consumer of the routine to determine what to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Use IF .. ELSE block

```
IF @chk = 0 
BEGIN

SELECT a.Ledgerid, 
       b.LedgerCity,
       CASE WHEN @chk = 0 THEN SUM(a.TotalAmount) ELSE SUM(a.NetAmount) END,
       CASE WHEN @chk = 0 THEN c.ledgername END  
FROM ExpenseMaster A
     LEFT JOIN LedgerAddress AS B ON A.LedgerID = B.LedgerID
     LEFT JOIN LedgerMaster AS C ON A.LedgerID = C.LedgerID  --This left join is required only if @chk=0, same logic is there in above select statement
GROUP BY A.LedgerID, B.LedgerCity, C.LedgerName;


END
ELSE
BEGIN

SELECT a.Ledgerid, 
       b.LedgerCity,
       CASE WHEN @chk = 0 THEN SUM(a.TotalAmount) ELSE SUM(a.NetAmount) END    
FROM ExpenseMaster A
LEFT JOIN LedgerAddress AS B ON A.LedgerID = B.LedgerID
GROUP BY A.LedgerID, B.LedgerCity;


END
```

Comment: i thought this option, but my production query is huge. So making changes will always require changes at two places if i use "IF ELSE". i am trying to keep one version only. I read some post which suggest " group by case when a=b then C or else d,e,f)". But that method is not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure, that no one from outside of the database can run your query and perform sql-injection, just use the simple dynamic-sql statement

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @chk AS INT= 0;

set @sql = N'SELECT a.Ledgerid, 
               b.LedgerCity, ' +
               CASE WHEN @chk = 0 THEN 'SUM(a.TotalAmount) ' ELSE 'SUM(a.NetAmount) ' END +
               CASE WHEN @chk = 0 THEN ', c.ledgername ' ELSE ' ' END +
        'FROM ExpenseMaster A
             LEFT JOIN LedgerAddress AS B ON A.LedgerID = B.LedgerID ' +
             CASE WHEN @chk=0 THEN 'LEFT JOIN LedgerMaster AS C ON A.LedgerID = C.LedgerID ' ELSE '' END +
        'GROUP BY A.LedgerID, 
                 B.LedgerCity' +
                 CASE WHEN @chk = 0 THEN ', C.LedgerName;' ELSE ';' END;

exec sp_executesql @sql
```